# Errors Configuring conform.nvim for Lazy-Vim: Undefined Globals and Types

Tags: neovim, lazyvim

I am following the **Full Spec** from the [official documentation](https://www.lazyvim.org/plugins/formatting) to configure conform.nvim for Lazy-Vim

However, I'm encountering multiple errors, one of which is that **Util** is not recognized, even though I believe it should be defined through some sort of initialization by lazy-vim itself.

Here are all the errors I encountered:

```
Undefined global Util.
Undefined global conform_opts.
Undefined type or alias conform.FormatterUnit.
Cannot assign string to conform.FormatterUnit.
Undefined type or alias conform.FormatterConfigOverride.
```

The official sample appears to have numerous errors. Is there an additional step I missed, or is the sample not intended for direct use? Any help resolving these issues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem...
This is my solution:

```
local M = {}
local Util = require("lazyvim.util")
```

You can find it in: https://github.com/LazyVim/LazyVim/tree/main/lua/lazyvim/util

This is my config for conform.nvim: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/luismanolo/nvim/develop/lua/plugins/conform.lua